# Batch command console output

Tags: windows, command-line

How do I write console output to a file? Not the output of the command but Windows execution of the commands.
I could not use my tags: Console Output Log

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you want. Where and how do you start your commands. Which output do you exactly require?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is the following:

```
 command > filename
```

Comment: The question is off topic for this site and will get closed

Comment: I know, thought I would help out anyways.